# SwiftUI - Regresar a una vista determinada tras realizar una acción

Tags: swift, navigation

Necesito volver a la vista inicial de mi APP tras realizar un `onLongTapGesture { }` en un elemento de una `List{ }`.

Detallo algo más, tengo una lista con información recogida mediante una petición GET a una API. Esa información la listo mediante el componente `List {}` de SwiftUI.

Al pulsar sobre un elemento, de la lista, la información que contiene se almacena en una base de datos y desaparece del listado.

Lo que me gustaría implementar sería una funcionalidad que volviese a una determinada vista tras el evento `onLongTapGesture{ }`.

Gracias

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:

1. Dentro del struct:

   @State private var goToView: Bool = false
2. Dentro del View:

   ```
   NavigationLink(destination: RepositoriosListView(), isActive: 
      self.$goToView) { EmptyView() }
   ```
3. En el evento:

   onLongPressGesture {
   // Agrego a la base de datos local lo que necesito
   self.goToView.toggle()
   }

Comment: ¡Gracias por la edición iGhost!

Comment: De nada , para eso estamos!